# High performance wifi router range extention

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm having some problems getting a reliable wifi network set up in a situation where I really need something high performance.

The situation is the following :
- location on 2 floors, ground floor and basement
- basement about 500 sq ft, ground floor about 1000 sq ft.
- large building with thick walls of solid concrete, lots of piping and wires around
- first floor contains a large 200 sq ft cold room

I basically need very good WiFi access everywhere on the two floors, since I have many people working with tablets doing inventory etc.

Here is the ground floor - for reference, the distance between the AP and the motor is around 30 feet :

[image]

I don't know if the problem is coming from interference from the motor or the fans, or if it's the thick concrete pillars which are located here and there.

I'd really appreciate some advice on what would be the best setup to get very good coverage into the "bad coverage zone", particularly inside the cold room at the back near the fans.

Since it's a business application, the budget is a bit less important than the results.

What I've tried :
- WiFi repeaters : limited success. The problem is I don't have an outlet inside the cold room.
- different routers : we started with a cheaper router, and then moved up to the Netgear N300, but while this helped a bit, it hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: Look into [Powerline Ethernet](https://www.amazon.com/Powerline-Computer-Network-Adapters/b?ie=UTF8&node=1194444) for a simple and cheap solution and get more WiFi routers connected on each floor, etc. to Powerline Ethernet ports. Read up on it, etc. and see if it'll suffice for your needs.